# Strange error in multiple format specifier

Tags: python, tuples

I'm pretty sure that the first 3 lines are correct, but I included them, so the code would be understandable.

```
print('a is going to be a tuple:\n')
a=(1,2,3) # tuple name: a
print('%d %d %d\n' % a) # Till here everything is correct, next I'm not sure
print('b is going to be a tuple as well:\n')
b=(4,5,'cow','says','moo')
print('%d %d %s %s %s \n' % (b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4]))
print('b will be a part of a\n')
a=(1,2,3,b)
print(a)
print('The whole set of characters is %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s') % (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3],a[3][4])
```

When  I run it (in a terminal), I get this output including the error message:

```
a is going to be a tuple:

1 2 3

b is going to be a tuple as well:

4 5 cow says moo 

b will be a part of a

(1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 'cow', 'says', 'moo'))
The whole set of characters is %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuples.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('The whole set of characters is %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s') % (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3],a[3][4])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

I don't understand the error message. What is it trying to say? I cannot see my error in the code, either.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your problem is that you're formatting values should be _inside_ of the call to print. You have them outside. Use `print('The whole set of characters is %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s' % (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3],a[3][4]))` instead.

Comment: If this is python 3 you should use `.format`, it's far more efficient than this

Comment: @ChristianDean oh yeh thanks (y), duh how newbie was that !!

Comment: True @JoshWeinstein. That's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

In Python the `%` operator for formatting the older strings is an infix operator, it cannot work across function call syntax.

For example,

```
foo = "The string is %s, the number is %d" % ("doo", 5)
```

In your code, your need to include the operator inside the parenthesis.

```
print('The whole set of characters is %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s' % (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3],a[3][4]))
```

Since your using python 3, and have a large number of fields in your format string, it might be more efficient to use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method of strings. This is where you can brace fields as names or indices, such as:

```
>>> "The count is {count}, the list is {lst}".format(count=5, lst=[1, 2])
'The count is 5, the list is [1, 2]'
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention your suggetion about using `.format` in your answer.